# Orientation lock in UINavigationController with UITabbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I want to lock orientation in few UIViewcontroller

1) Loginview (support portrait Only ) UIViewcontroller having login button

2) On login button i call UITabbarController from storyboard, having 3tabs all tab are embedded UINavigationControllers.(Tab1,Tab2,Tab3)

3) On Tab1 (support both landscape and portrait )having button button1, from which i am push a UIViewcontroller Demo(support portrait Only ). like below

```
 Demo *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Demo"];
    vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

The Demo is loaded successfully , but i want to lock its rotation to portrait so i create a Category of UINavigationController, but it still rotating.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UINavigationController (Orientation)

@end
```

//==========

```
#import "UINavigationController+Orientation.h"
@implementation UINavigationController (Orientation)
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;;
}
@end
```

//------- Inside my Demo uiviewcontroller i but below code but it never called --------

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

**I read many post but non of them help ,Please Help me out how do i do it?**

Answer (score 2):

Initial set orientation as **Portrait** only in Targets -> General -> Deployment Info (See Image Below)

[image]

In **AppDelegate.h** declare property:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL shouldRotate;
```

In **AppDelegate.m** define

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    if (self.shouldRotate)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

In **UIViewController Implemenatation** set shouldRotate value like:

If you want to rotate then set YES

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setShouldRotate:YES];
    }
```

else set NO

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setShouldRotate:NO];
}
```

> **Note:** **setShouldRotate:**  always call in **viewDidAppear:**. So, whenever you switch the UIViewController it will work properly.

Hope this will work for you. All the best :)

Comment: thanks yeshica...for help...but if user in landscape mode then the jump view also shown in Landscape....

Comment: @iphonemaclover: `setShouldRotate` value as `NO` in that ViewController `viewDidAppear' method.

Comment: @iphonemaclover: If you found this code helpful don't just Thanks mark Accepted as well.

Comment: already up vote for it @Yashica ....but accepted answer should be in working condition...so it will resolve my question and also helps other users...